# Python - Appending data from one xlsx to another existing xlsx

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlutils

I have gone through many existing questions about the same, but didn't find any satisfactory answer to my problem.

Here's a bunch of code for appending values from xlsx to existing xlsx:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("cik_list.xlsx")

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

X0 = []; X1 = []; X2 = []; X3 = []; X4 = []; X5 = []
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    X0.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    X1.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 1))
    X2.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 2))
    X3.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 3))
    X4.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 4))
    X5.append(sheet.cell_value(row, 5))

rb = xlrd.open_workbook("Output Data Structure.xlsx")

r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

r = sheet.nrows 
wb1 = copy(rb)

sheet1 = wb1.get_sheet(0)

row=1
while(row < r):
    row=1
    for x in X0:
        sheet1.write(row, 0, x)
        row+=1
    row=1
    for x in X1:
        sheet1.write(row, 1, x)
        row+=1
    row=1
    for x in X2:
        sheet1.write(row, 2, x)
        row+=1
    row=1
    for x in X3:
        sheet1.write(row, 3, x)
        row+=1
    row=1
    for x in X4:
        sheet1.write(row, 4, x)
        row+=1
    row=1
    for x in X5:
        sheet1.write(row, 5, x)
        row+=1

wb1.save("Output Data Structure.xls")
```

Is there any way out I can save the `Output Data Structure` as `.xlsx` file without changing the first half of the code i.e. reading the values from `cik_list.xlsx` and storing them into 6 different lists.

Thanks

Comment: From the library's [quickstart](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) `for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    print(sh.row(rx))`

Comment: As its author says there `you should no longer be using these unless you have a particular 
need to work with .xls files. If you only work with .xlsx files, and 
that's the only Excel format you should look to create nowadays, then 
you should be using openpyxl instead.`

Comment: I also want to work with .xlsx and wanna know how to append 6 different lists into the 6 columns using openpyxl

Comment: *Don't* work with columns in the first place. Work with rows or better yet, cell ranges

Comment: Thanks for the advice @PanagiotisKanavos, I got a way out with `openpyxl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few changes in the lower half of the code, I got it working absolutely fine.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

rb = load_workbook("Output Data Structure.xlsx")

sheet1 = rb.active

r = sheet.nrows 

row=2
while(row <= r):
    row=2
    for x in X0:
        sheet1.cell(row, 1, x)
        row+=1
    row=2
    for x in X1:
        sheet1.cell(row, 2, x)
        row+=1
    row=2
    for x in X2:
        sheet1.cell(row, 3, x)
        row+=1
    row=2
    for x in X3:
        sheet1.cell(row, 4, x)
        row+=1
    row=2
    for x in X4:
        sheet1.cell(row, 5, x)
        row+=1
    row=2
    for x in X5:
        sheet1.cell(row, 6, x)
        row+=1

rb.save("Output Data Structure.xlsx")
```

Any further improvements would be highly appreciable.

Thanks